# Replacing some of a attribute value with XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

After some search on the internet I can't find a answer to this. My knowledge and experience is novice..

My xml-file:

```
<figuregroup id="1408-46-00-4506">
                 <figure id="1408-46-00-4507"
                         href="http://A_Internet_Location/Images/img3.tif"
                         height="5.098in"
                         width="2.798in"
                         align="acenter"
                         placement="break"
                         orient="port"/>
                 <title id="Pt2Ch3-1408-46-00-4508">fig title</title>
</figuregroup>
```

I want the xml-file after an xslt processing to look something like this:

```
<figuregroup id="1408-46-00-4506">
                     <figure id="1408-46-00-4507"
                             href="img3.tif"
                             height="5.098in"
                             width="2.798in"
                             align="acenter"
                             placement="break"
                             orient="port"/>
                     <title id="Pt2Ch3-1408-46-00-4508">fig title</title>
</figuregroup>
```

Only change is that the href attribute is reduced to img3.tif

What I have tried so fare:

```
 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
 <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
 </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

   <xsl:template match="figure[contains(@href, 'http://A_Internet_Location/Images/')]">


    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains(@href, 'http://A_Internet_Location/Images/')">
        <xsl:call-template name="remove">
             <xsl:with-param name="value" select="@href"/>
        </xsl:call-template> 
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template> 

    <xsl:template name="remove">
    <xsl:param name="value"/>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(substring-before($value, 'http://A_Internet_Location/Images/'), substring-after($value, 'http://A_Internet_Location/Images/'))"/>
</xsl:template>
```

This is doing everything right, but not reducing the href attribute.
All help is appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is what you could do if there is an unknown amount of `/` in the attribute value that you need to get rid of. Defining a named template is a good idea if your stylesheet should work both with XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0.

The named template `recursive-substring` has the parameters `$string` and `$anchor`. It outputs the substring of `$string` that is *after* the last occurrence of `$anchor` in `$string`.

**Stylesheet**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="figure/@href">
        <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:call-template name="recursive-substring">
                <xsl:with-param name="anchor" select="'/'"/>
                <xsl:with-param name="string" select="."/>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="recursive-substring">
        <xsl:param name="anchor"/>
        <xsl:param name="string"/>

        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="contains($string,$anchor)">
                <xsl:call-template name="recursive-substring">
                    <xsl:with-param name="anchor" select="'/'"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="string" select="substring-after($string,$anchor)"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="$string"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**XML Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<figuregroup id="1408-46-00-4506">
    <figure id="1408-46-00-4507" href="img3.tif" height="5.098in" width="2.798in" align="acenter" placement="break" orient="port"/>
    <title id="Pt2Ch3-1408-46-00-4508">fig title</title>
</figuregroup>
```

Comment: Is there any reason you have written a `version="2.0"` stylesheet and then used `<xsl:sequence select="$string"/>` as an XSLT 2.0 only feature? Your introduction says "Defining a named template is a good idea if your stylesheet should work both with XSLT 1.0 and XSLT 2.0" but in that case I would expect the posted code to show a solution that works in XSLT 1.0. Or if you really wanted to use XSLT 2.0 then you could simply use `<xsl:attribute name="href" select="tokenize(., '/')[last()]"/>`.

Comment: @MartinHonnen That's indeed a mistake, thanks - I'll correct it as soon as I have the time.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Thanks for your comment, should be fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, ok, this is not xslt

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use XML::DT;                       # attributes: %v; content: $c; tag: $q
use strict;

print dt($ARGV[0], figure => sub{ $v{href} =~ s!.*/!!; toxml } );
```

It may be necessary to adapt the substitution `s!.*/!!`

Disclaim: I am one of the authors of XML::DT

Comment: The OP wanted an `XSLT` solution, not a `Perl` solution. Your answer is irrelevant.